# Adding new line in string in JSP

Tags: java, xml, string, jsp

I'm trying to pass a string as a request attribute to JSP.
reuqest.setAttriute("string", xml);

The string comes from xml file which is parsed using following code:

```
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);    
DOMImplementationLS domImplementation = (DOMImplementationLS) doc.getImplementation();
LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementation.createLSSerializer();
String string= lsSerializer.writeToString(doc);
```

When I put this string on the console, I can see nice formatted output (exactly as in XML file, new lines are kept).

When I'm trying to display that string in JSP, I observe not formatted code, the String does not tarnsform new line signs.

This is the code from JSP:

I was trying to use `fn:replac`e function, but it also did not work (I was trying to transform 'a' latter instead of `'\n'` just for tests to ommit problems with special characters). I can see `<br />` tags in displayed string but it is not transformed to new lines.

```
<c:set var="string2" value='${fn:replace(string, "a", "<br />")}' />
```

Comment: Maybe a `<pre>${string}</pre>` suffices, without replaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are displaying the `string2`, if you are displaying it using JSTL, which I think you are, you need to set escapeXml attribute to false explicitly. Becasue by default JSTL escapeXml attribute is true, which would render tags such as `<br/>` as it is in plain text format. So while displaying the string in JSP, use it like below

```
<c:out value="${string}" escapeXml="false" />
```

this would interpret any `br` tags in your string as line breaks

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks